# python style: inline function that needs no inlining?

Tags: python, coding-style, performance, closures

I'mm writing gtk code. I often have short callbacks that don't need to be closures, as they are passed all the parameters they need. For example, I have this in a loop when creating some `gtk.TreeViewColumns`:

```
def widthChanged(MAINCOL, SPEC, SUBCOL, expandable):
    if expandable: return
    w = MAINCOL.get_width()
    SUBCOL.set_fixed_width(w)

cl.connect("notify::width", widthChanged, pnlcl, expand)
```

This is probably inefficient, since the function is being created on every iteration of the loop (side-question: is it actually, or is it optimized?). However, I feel like if I moved all these one-liners to the top level, the code would be more confusing. Any opinions?

Comment: Couldn't this particular example be written cl.connect("notify::width", lambda maincol, spec, subcol, expandable: subcol.set_fixed_width(maincol.get_width()) if not expandable else None, pnlcl, expand)... not sure if that's more or less readable though, but at least it's one def less.

Comment: yeah but my point stands: it's less efficient than having a top-level function. also might be less readable than this version, so it's worse in both ways =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go with whatever style is most readable. Don't worry about speed unless your code profiling tools have told you that the area is a hotspot.